# IIS 7 URL rewrite not working

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config

Need to set friendly URLs for ASP classic web site running on IIS 7 .

http://SUB.DOMAIN.org/chatter/default.aspx?article=1000 should become 
http://SUB.DOMAIN.org/chatter/article10.aspx

There is this rules in my web.config

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="chatter">
                <match url="^chatter/default.aspx?article=([0-9]+)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="chatter/article{R:1}.aspx" />
                <conditions>
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^www\.SUB\.DOMAIN\.org$" />
                </conditions>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Nothing happens when I apply this rule. Please note  there is subdomain included. Any help ?

Comment: It seems like that the condition won't match. It is looking for query string to match the domain.

Comment: You simply misunderstood what is URL rewrite so hope you can learn from basic examples.

Comment: and what is the URL rewrite ?